# How to reference numpy matrix as Excel indexes

Tags: python, excel, numpy, matrix

Suppose i have a numpy matrix like this

```
[['first_row' '95' '93' '90' '278']
 ['second_row' '88' '500' '400' '988']]
```

Now, when i say something like `B1*B2`, i need to access the `B1` and `B2` index of the matrix and perform multiplication (Similar to Excel). How can i achieve this in Python?

```
         A          B     C     D     E
 1  [['first_row'  '95'  '93'  '90' '278']
 2   ['second_row' '88'  '500' '400' '988']]
```

Comment: Do you need the solution in numpy only? Or would pandas be fine?

Comment: Pandas is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ahcieve something similar (not exactly same) using `pandas` framework and `DataFrame`, You can start looking at pandas.DataFrame documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) .

Example code -

```
In [6]: import pandas as pd

In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],columns=['A','B','C','D'])

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8

In [12]: df['A'][0]
Out[12]: 1

In [13]: df['B'][1]
Out[13]: 6
```

You can look at tutorials online to get started in this.

Comment: Is there any way to automate the column name without manually specifying them and to start the row index from 1?

Comment: You can create a function in python that accepts the two lettered numbers like `B0` or `A1` , and converts them into corresponding 'B' and 0, etc and accesses the element